# Java Stripe API

Tags: java, stripe-payments

I'm trying to bind a token as a customer card. So, this token has been created by [Stripe.js](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe.js?). So, then I send this code on my backend service and I'm trying to set it up into a customer's cards:

```
Card card = Token.retrieve(id).getCard();
```

So, once I've got this `token` as a card, I'm trying it:

```
Customer.retrieve(this.customer).getSources().create(card.getMetadata())
```

Nevertheless, I'm getting this compilation error:

> The method create(Map) in the type ExternalAccountCollection is not applicable for the arguments (Map)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the documentation for adding a card to an existing customer object here: https://stripe.com/docs/api/java#create_card.

The correct code would be:

```
Customer customer = Customer.retrieve(this.customer);
Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
params.put("source", id);
Card card = customer.getSources().create(params);
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you load stripe.js and open stripe payment popup and submit, after stripe return token like(tok_kgkjfdskjfd) the this token pass as source into below api and stripe will automatically save the your card object.

```
Customer c = Customer.retrieve(this.customer);
Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
params.put("source", above_token);
Card card = customer.getSources().create(params);
```